# How to get the view definition in SQL server using NodeJS through code

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am having a requirement where I need to change the definition of view based on the user requirement.
Suppose if the definition of the view is like this:

`create view view_name as select tableA.col_3 as colTabA3 from tableA ,tableB where 1=1;`

now if the user has a requirement such that colTabA3 column should have the data from tableB.col_3 then I need to change the view definition to

`create view view_name as select tableB.col_3 as colTabA3 from tableA ,tableB where 1=1;`

I am going to show some UI to the user to give the expression for colTabA3 and when he gives the expression then I will have to get the definition of the table, modify that definition and add the new expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('${view_name}')) AS ObjectDefinition;
```

this query is giving the view definition, I can connect to the database through code and run this query to get the view definition.